# How to decompose a matrix into the outer product of two vectors?

Tags: matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have a matrix $M$ and I would like to find two vectors $u$ and $v$, that minimize

$$ \sum_{i,j} (M_{i,j}-u_iv_j)^2  $$

How can I do this (numerically)?

Actually this is very simplified compared to my actual problem. For instance, I dont really have a full matrix, but only values for some range of $(i,j)$. However, I think once I know how to solve it in the general case, it should be straightforward to skip certain entries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, note that $\Sigma_{ij} (M_{ij}-u_iv_j)^2 = \|M-uv^T\|_F^2$, where $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the *Frobenius norm* of a matrix. If you're doing a Google search that may be helpful.

In the unconstrained case, there is an analytic solution given by the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). That is: let $M=U\Sigma V^T$ be the SVD of $M$, with the singular values arranged in nonincreasing order along the diagonal of $\Sigma$. Then the triple $(\sigma_1,u_1,v_1)$ formed from the first singular value, the first column of $U$, the first column of $V$, respectively, can be used to compute your $u$ and $v$. For instance, $u=\sigma_1 u_1$, $v=v_1$ would work, but really any $u=\alpha\sigma_1 u_1$, $v=\alpha^{-1} v_1$ for $\alpha\neq 0$ will work as well.

In the constrained case, unfortunately, you have a nonconvex optimization problem on your hands. Presumably you have a problem like this:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & \|M-uv^T\|_F^2 \\
\text{subject to} & L_{ij} \leq M_{ij} \leq U_{ij} \quad \forall i,j
\end{array}
where $L$ and $U$ are lower and upper bound matrices (possibly with infinite entries where you have missing information). This is an extreme (e.g., rank-1) version of a [low-rank approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization) problem.

There is a variety of literature about this, but again, it's nonconvex, which means that it's not easy to solve in practice. A common technique is to *alternate* between minimizing over $u$ (holding $v$ fixed) and minimizing over $v$ (holding $u$ fixed). There is no guarantee this gives you the best solution though.

EDIT: A simpler way to look at the problem where you know only a portion of the elements of $M$ is that you're minimizing only over the indices that you know: that is,
$$\text{minimize} ~ \sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}} (M_{ij}-u_iv_j)^2$$
for some index set $\mathcal{I}$. After all, for the elements you *don't* know, you might as well just set $M_{ij}=u_iv_j$ after you've determined the $u$ and $v$ you prefer, so they will contribute 0 to the final Frobenius objective. Alas, that doesn't make the problem any easier; it's still nonconvex.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Actually I was working with SVD recently and I could have known that this is the way to go... I dont fully understand the second part of what you wrote. What do you mean with $L$ and $U$ as constraints? I mean when I have $M$  given, then they are just $L=M$ and $U=M$, isnt it? Maybe I will understand after reading the links you provided....

Comment: You said that you didn't know $M$ completely, just some of the values. So for the $(i,j)$ entries that you know, you have $L_{ij}=U_{ij}=M_{ij}$. For those you don't know at all, you have $L_{ij}=-\infty$, $U_{ij}=+\infty$ (in other words, you just drop that constraint). If you have some sensible bounds fore these missing values of $M$, you could use them. Regardless, without full information about $M$, you have a nonconvex optimization problem, and that's the difficult one.

Comment: Added one more paragraph.

Comment: I think I understood. I am just a bit confused that you call the case where I dont know all entries (i.e. the one with less contraints) the "constrained case"

Comment: Well, I renamed it to "nonconvex" to avoid that confusion. Suffice it to say this: one of the more natural ways to express the model where some of the values of $M$ are missing is as a constrained problem. But it's not *that* important to get that right now: the real problem is that the missing value case is *hard*.

Comment: The very first \sigma should be a \Sigma, however there seems to be no way to fix this since an edit must be at least 6 characters...

Comment: Wait, did you just delete and then retype the 'igma' part and the program bought that as extra characters? I should remember that for future occasions!

Comment: It's possible that as the original post author, I can make fixes you cannot.

Comment: Although the problem is nonconvex, I tried it with some random data for $M$ using a local NLP solver (CONOPT). In almost all cases it converges to the global optimum (when given a nonzero starting point). So may be a heuristic approach would be to solve this thing a few times with different starting points using a standard NLP solver.